# ScrollViewer items different on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8

When I run my program on Windows 8, items in ScrollViewer have additional margins on all sides, on some ListBox-es item background is missing and there is also unappealing item highlighting. Can I force it to render exactly like on Windows 7?

Adding to each

```
<setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/> 
<setter Property="ListBoxItem.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
```

seems to fix the problem but background still has hightlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 8, the default system theme for WPF is different than the old Aero theme from Windows 7.  I *think* the Windows 8 theme exists alongside the old Aero theme, so you could try injecting the Aero assets into your application on startup:

```
try
{
    var uri = new Uri(
        "PresentationFramework.Aero;component\\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml", 
        UriKind.Relative);

    var aeroResources = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;
    if (aeroResources != null)
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(aeroResources);
}
catch
{
    //
    // Proceed with the current theme.
    //
}
```

Note that this will make your *entire* application appear as it does under Windows 7 (not just `ListBox` items).

Comment: Thanks. I will restyle everything for Windows 8 since it would not make sense to use Aero in Windows 8.